# The brake lever of Shimano's BL-MT200 is too long for me, can I modified it to a shorter one?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, brake-levers

The brake lever of Shimano's BL-MT200 is too long for me, can I modify it to a shorter one?

Comment: How can it be too long? If your hands are too small, you should be able to adjust its reach with a hex key.

Comment: Please clarify - is "too long" meaning the whole lever is long (ie enough space for 4 fingers) or is it too far away from your bars while riding ?

Comment: ...sorry for that sirs, what I mean is instead the lever is for 2-3 fingers use, can  I cut it to one finger lever? But in order to do that, I need steps in removing the levers from the body, it seems for me do not know how to do that!!!

Comment: Why not just move the brakes further inboard? I.e. towards the stem. Then you have less lever hanging over your grips.

Comment: You will likely not have enough power if you restrict yourself to one finger. Consider upgrading to proper one-finger levers.

Answer (score 4):

MT200 has what is called  Reach Adjustment - which brings the level closer to the handle bars. To do this you need  a small hex key (Can't remember i its 2 or 2.5mm).
[image: Reach Adjustment]

Also when mounting the brakes you are best to mount them inboard with about 2-3cm from the handgrip. I prefer to have the shifters mounted outboard of the brake lever, but thats personal preference.

[image]